# fgets error on big cvs files

Tags: php, mysql, fopen, fgetcsv

I have got a couple of custom scripts running on my server to extract CSV files from a template. These files are sometimes 250,000 + lines. When i reach around this point I get this error.

> Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=24022

This is linked to the packet size in the mysql query not been big enough.

I increased the mysql query size with the below, it seemed to improve it but not all the way.

```
    SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
    set global max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
    set global net_buffer_length=1048576;
```

I am using a dedicated server and have lots of resource so i could increase this but am unsure how much is safe + not really sure if this is the best way to handle the situation

Below is the code that i am using (i have removed a lot of the code that is just confusing)

```
 $br = ']'; //this changes
 $handle = fopen($path."".$inputFileName, "r");
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "".$br."")) !== FALSE) 
     {
    ....... my code .... based on $data["...
```

Comment: What are you actually doing inside the loop? because fgetcsv() isn't what's causing the problem with that error message.... Are you trying to build one giant query to do a single db request with all the CSV data?

Comment: Actually, i have uncommented everything inside the loop and i still get the issue

Comment: sounds like one of variables inside the loop is not initialized for every loops. Could you post whole codes plz?

Comment: `Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=24022 

This is linked to the packet size in the mysql query not been big enough
` has nothing to do with fgetcsv() and everything to do with MySQL database queries, so what's going on in that loop that could affect a database query?

Comment: Show **all relevant code** or all you are going to get are **guesses**

Comment: no reply with any useful extra data.... I am off

Comment: Ok. I am deleting every thing from the loop including some queries that i thought were causing no issue. I will be back with my results.Thank you

Comment: THANK YOU SO much, It was an update query. This is obviously why i could not find any thing as I was looking in the wrong place

Comment: How do i give you both credit for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was my scripts (many) where taking a long time to run. Basically i just reconnected to Mysql. All comments were here helpful